# How to pass a String sentence as Command Line Argument

Tags: python, shell, argparse

The following code takes single String values which can be retrieved on the Python side. How can one do this with a sentence String with spaces?

```
from sys import argv

script, firstargument = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", firstargument
```

To run that I would pass arguments as such :

```
$ python test.py firstargument
```

Which would output

```
The script is called:test.py
Your first variable is:firstargument
```

An example input could be "Hello world the program runs" and I want to pass this as a command line argument to be stored in the 'first' variable.

Comment: Exactly like that. `test.py "Hello world the program runs"`

Comment: So it requires quotes "" unlike my example.

Comment: Also your variable should be `first` not `firstargument`

Comment: @RichardSmith, the quotes aren't visible to Python at all; they're interpreted *by the shell*, and tell it how to split contents into the argv array (which, again, is something *the shell* does before it ever starts Python).

Comment: See `man execv` for the underlying family of C library calls used to start another program on UNIX -- you'll see that any program starting another program on UNIX needs to provide an *array* of C strings as arguments (and that array is named `argv`, unless using a varargs-based calling convention allowing each element of that array to be passed as a distinct argument to the call).

Comment: `test.py Hello\ world\ the\ program\ runs` would, btw, be an exact equivalent -- as in, the shell invokes the exact same thing, such that the Python interpreter has no way of knowing the difference between the two invocations. Same for `s='Hello world the program runs'; test.py "$s"` (but *not* `test.py $s`).

Answer (score 6):

argv will be a  list of all the arguments that the shell parses.

So if I make

```
#script.py
from sys import argv
print argv

$python script.py hello, how are you
['script.py','hello','how','are','you]
```

the name of the script is always the first element in the list. If we don't use quotes, each word will also become an element of the list.

```
print argv[1]
print argv[2]
$python script.py hello how are you
hello
how
```

But if we use quotes,

```
$python script.py "hello, how are you"
 ['script.py','hello, how are you']
```

The all words are now one item in the list. So do something like this

```
print "The script is called:", argv[0] #slicing our list for the first item
print "Your first variable is:", argv[1]
```

Or if you don't want to use quotes for some reason:

```
print "The script is called:", argv[0] #slicing our list for the first item
print "Your first variable is:", " ".join(argv[1:]) #slicing the remaining part of our list and joining it as a string.

$python script.py hello, how are you
$The script is called: script.py
$Your first variable is: hello, how are you
```

Comment: The "if you don't want to use quotes" version is buggy. If the OP puts three spaces together, it'll be replaced with just one; if the OP puts a `*`, it'll be replaced with a list of filenames; etc. When we're building an answer for someone who a priori doesn't know how the process works, an answer that incorporates caveats should call them out explicitly.

Comment: Thats true, there are hundreds of ways to mess up a join. But it was more of an fyi.

Comment: Yes -- the point I'm trying to argue is that such an FYI where the approach isn't really production-usable or good practice should be *explicitly called out as such in the answer*, so someone doesn't get a wrong impression.

Answer (score 1):

Multi word command line arguments, that is single value arguments that contain multiple ASCII sequences separated by the space character `%20` have to be enclosed with quotes on the command line.

```
$ python test.py "f i r s t a r g u m e n t"
```

```
The script is called:test.py
Your first variable is:f i r s t a r g u m e n t
```

This is actually not related to Python at all, but to the way [your shell parses the command line arguments.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-3)